$R = \mathbb R[X,Y]/(XY - 1)$ and $I$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by the image of the element $X - Y$ in $R$. Describe $R/I$
Let $R = \mathbb R[X,Y]/(XY - 1)$ ($\mathbb R$ is the set of real numbers)  and I be the ideal of R generated by the image of the element X - Y in R.
I want to find a way to describe R/I, i.e. find a more familiar ring
which is isomorphic to R/I so that I can deduce whether R/I is an intergral domain or a field, as well as describe the maximal ideals in R/I.
Here is what I have tried so far. My idea is to set up a surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb R[X,Y]$ to a more familiar ring $R'$ such that the kernel of this homomorphism is the ideal $(XY - 1)$. This way, I would have $\mathbb R[X,Y]/(XY - 1) ≃ R'$. From here, it would be easier to describe R/I.
However, I am having a hard time defining such a homomorphism. Given that $1,x,y$ are generators of $R = \mathbb R[X,Y]$, I am aware that I need to just define my homomorphism $\phi$ for $1,x,y$ such that $\phi(xy - 1) = 0$. Is this the right approach to this problem?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Hint: $R/I \cong \Bbb R[x]/(x^2-1)$.

Thank you for your suggestion @JoséCarlosSantos. I have edited the question accordingly. Is the question better formulated now?

@Amateur_Algebraist, thank you for your hint. Given this, I can see how the nature of $R/I$ could be deduced. However, I am unable to see how you arrived at the isomorphism you specified. Could you elaborate on it? Thanks

$R/I = \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy-1,x-y)$ by theorem of correspondence. Can you represent $y$ with a polynomial in $x$ with the two relations? If so, use the evaluation map to find the isomorphism.
